# How to convert generic parameter into enum?

Tags: typescript, generics

How can you convert a generic parameter into an enum with minimal run-time performance overhead?

i.e. how to complete the Get below such that `MyClass.Get<Dog>` returns `eDog`?

```
interface IAnimal {}
class Dog implements IAnimal {}
class Cat implements IAnimal {}

enum Animals { eDog = 0, eCat = 1 }; 

class MyClass {
    static Get<T extends IAnimal>() : Animals {
        return ...?
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no relation between the enum and the class. so other than a switch nothing you can do with the classes you provide

Comment: @titian-cernicova-dragomir **than (sorry)

Comment: How can you compare the type? Is there an equivalent of C# typeof() you can call on the generic parameter?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You can't do a switch over a generic.

Comment: @daw Generics (and generally anything related with types) are lost when compiled, so you can't do typeof over a generic type.

Comment: @lilezek yep... is there any work-around besides instantiating the type?

Comment: @lilezek you can switch over constructors ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type parameters are erased at compile time, so we can't use them to get any information at runtime. What we can do is use the ability to pass constructors around as parameters instead.

Using constructors as parameters you could do one of two things:

You could define a static field on the class and use that in your function

```
function Get(cls: { new (...args: any[]): IAnimal, type: Animals}) : Animals {
    return cls.type;
}
//Usage
class Dog implements IAnimal { static type: Animals.eCat}
class Cat implements IAnimal { static type: Animals.eCat}
console.log(Get(Dog));
console.log(Get(Cat));
```

Or use a `switch` over class constructors:

```
function Get(cls:  new (...args: any[]) => IAnimal, ) : Animals {
    switch(cls)
    {
        case Dog: return Animals.eDog;
        case Cat: return Animals.eCat;
    }
}
//Usage
console.log(Get(Dog));
console.log(Get(Cat));
```

Comment: Great! The "new" in the lambda type is unfamilar to me, can't find it in the docs, can you explain or point me where to look in docs please?

Comment: It's called a constructor signature, it allows you to specify a class constructor, not a regular function

Comment: Hmm can't call your Get from a function which has the generic parameter e.g.  "CallGet<T extends IAnimal>() : Animals { return Get(T); }"  so its not solving the problem - still stuck trying to convert a type to a value.

Comment: @daw generics are erased at compile time. To get anything at runtime you need to pass as an argument the constructor instead

Comment: Yep, thanks. If you can add that comment to the top of your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen usually in TypeScript is:

```
interface IAnimal { type: Animals; }
class Dog implements IAnimal { type: eDog; }
class Cat implements IAnimal { type: eCat; }

enum Animals { eDog = 0, eCat = 1 }; 

...
```

Note: I've not checked if this code compiles.